# Asp.net div still not accessible after runat="server"

Tags: asp.net

I have a `div` element in my HTML. I added a `id` and `runat` attributes to the element:

```
<div id="footer" runat="server">
```

After rendering, viewing the HTML shows:

```
<div id="ctl00_footer">
```

However, I cannot access it from the page's .aspx.cs code:

```
footer.InnerHtml += "test";
```

How do I access that element from the C# code?

Answer (score 4):

you can use FindControl("footer"), and cast it to HtmlGenericControl.

```
HtmlGenericControl footer = (HtmlGenericControl)FindControl("footer")
```

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Tools.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\page.aspx.cs:42
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +24
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +41
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +65
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2427

Comment: I would guess if you can't access the control this way then you've probably messed something up on page.aspx which means that studio will be unable to update the designer file.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons can be that you don't have designer file for that page. So you can't access element by it's `ID`.

Just add class with name ***[your page name].aspx.designer.cs***, open it, remove all code, save it, go to your view and click save - designer must generate code of all elements from your view. After this you can access element by `ID`.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem accessing `<div id="footer" runat="server"></div>` the way you are doing. Strange though, my generated markup keeps the div id unchanged as `footer`.
Make sure you don't have any compile errors, and that you can access other elements running server-side in the same scope you are trying to access this div.

Comment: Well, in my case it just changes it to "ctl00_footer"

Comment: @user101579 Have you tried the two things I mentioned in my last sentence?

Comment: @user101579 Also, where does this <div sit in your markup? Is it nested inside some asp controls? Maybe that is your issue. If so, you might need to access them differently. Could you post its surrounding and actual code in your post?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the ClientIDMode property of the page or control to Static:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

This will prevent the "ctl00_" from being appended to the ID which is what is causing you the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem before. You may have the target div inside another div that does not have the `runat="server"` attribute. All nested divs should have the `runat` attribute in order to be able to access the inner elements.

```
<div id="divContainer" runat="Server">
    <div id="yourDiv" runat="Server">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to code ASP.NET and you want to access the control from the server-side, you may as well use the provided controls.

Use a [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) instead of a Div.  The ASP:Panel control renders as a div in the generated html anyway.  The Panel doesn't have  a .Text property, but you can add controls to it from code-behind (such as a [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.aspx) or a [LiteralControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx).

Comment: You can, but... (added the response to this in the first sentence of my answer).   For a silly comparison to illustrate the point: You can use a motorcycle to haul furniture if you try hard enough, but it's not what it was designed for.  Use the tool designed for the job.  Why be different when the right tool just works?  If you use the right control you don't have to mess with casting to an HtmlGenericControl. *Result: Cleaner code, easier for the maintenance programmer to understand.*

Comment: While I mostly agree with David and would suggest using a Panel if you can, do keep in mind that depending on your version of ASP.NET and the browser you are rendering for, a Panel might not ALWAYS render as a div (although this only applies to version < 3)

Comment: @Porco - you're right.  I keep forgetting about the fact that it will render differently based on the browser automatically.  Using a div does give finer control, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Is there possibly a chance that the page was copy/pasted when being created?  If so, make absolutely sure that all references to the old page are changed to the name of the new page.  I've done this before within the code at the top of the ASPX page, as well as the namespace of the designer page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found out that due to a "copy" and "paste" my function had a "static" declaration.
Removed it since static functions can't access non-static identifiers and it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
My solution was to have 'ID' instead of 'id' for the div element (i.e. the casing was the reason).